# Union of power sets of the counting numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, ($\mathbb{N}$ being the natural numbers set), let $ C_{n} $ be the set of counting numbers from $ 1 $ to $ n $, so that $ C_{n} = \{1, 2, ..., n\}, $ and let $ P(A) $ be the power set of of a set $ A $.  My question is whether $ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(C_{n})} = P(\mathbb{N}) $ ?

I believe this seems true because on the LHS above, we have a union of an infinite number of power sets of the counting number sets, $ C_{1}, C_{2}, ...$, so this should give us all of the subsets of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, which by definition is $P(\mathbb{N})$ on the RHS.

However in the book they argue that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(C_{n})}$ consists of all finite sets of counting numbers, while $P(\mathbb{N})$ contains all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, including infinite ones, therefore they are not equal. However I don't understand why they are saying that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(C_{n})}$ consists of only *finite* sets?

Comment: It's an infinite set that its elements are finite.

Comment: Thanks everyone, and in particular thanks @ypercube; this is exactly what tripped me up in my thinking, so we are unioning a bunch of finite power sets and the overall union is infinite, but each power set element that is added to the union is finite, and so something like the set of all primes (as @MarkFischler mentioned below) is a subset of the natural numbers set, but it's infinite, and could not be made from any of the individual power set elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if $A\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal P(C_n)$, then there exists some $n$ such that $A\in\mathcal P(C_n)$. Therefore $A\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and so $A$ must be finite.

So indeed $\Bbb N$ itself is not in this union, despite the fact that the union is infinite, since $\Bbb N$ is not a finite set for itself.

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense, and maybe what is throwing me off is the infinity symbol on the top of the big union. The way I'm visualizing it is similar to an infinite sum; i.e. that if we take a union of an infinite number of finite power sets, then how could it lead to a finite result? Is it wrong to think this way?

Comment: The union itself is not a finite set. That's true, $\bigcup\mathcal P(C_n)$ is not a finite set. But its elements are. Just like how $\Bbb N=\bigcup C_n$ is an infinite set, but all its elements are finite.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly for all $n$ you have $C_n \subset \mathbb{N}$, so $P(C_n) \subset P( \mathbb{N} )$. In particular $\bigcup_n P(C_n) \subset P( \mathbb{N} )$.

Now, pick $X \in \bigcup_n P(C_n)$. Then, by definition of union, $X \in P(C_n) $ for some $n$. But this implies that $X$ is finite. This means that $\bigcup_n P(C_n) \neq P( \mathbb{N} )$. For example, $\mathbb{N} \notin \bigcup_n P(C_n)$, otherwise it would be a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all primes is not in any $P(C_n)$ yet it is in $P(\Bbb{N})$

Comment: That's not quite the question the OP asks.